# why hitting refresh button is not calling the view method of the page's url?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have django supported web application. when i hit refresh button on a page the view method corresponding to the page's url is not being called. But it gets called when i re-enter the url in th address bar. can any one suggest the reason and the solution?

Comment: Try Shift+Reload, it ignores the browser cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the ans: just add the new tab command to your html page itself

Answer (score 0):

check caching.

1. first check cache meta tags on the client
2. then check web server cache

Note: "GET" requets some times cached on the server or client automatically.

Comment: i am on server..client is on remote location..... i want to call view method whenever client hits refresh button....